# How does Ember-Data track associated data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to come to terms with ember-data and how the associations work.

This is an application using ember with rails.

I've got the following:

```
App.Permission = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  group: DS.belongsTo('group')
});

App.Group = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  permissions: DS.hasMany('permission', {async: true}),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user')
});

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  password: DS.attr('string'),
  groups: DS.hasMany('group', {async: true})
});
```

For groups, I have two lists, unselected and selected.  HTML5 drag-and-drop is being used to pull the data from one list to the other.  For my selected data, in my controller, I have this:

```
selectedPermissions: function() {
  return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    sortProperties: ['name'],
    content: this.get('permissions')
  });
}.property('model.selectedPermissions')
```

And this works PERFECTLY!  Any permission pulled over to the selected side is automatically saved and associated with the group.

Now, for users, again, two lists, unselected and selected, and the same setup as above.  For the selected data in the users controller, I have this:

```
selectedGroups: function() {
  return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    sortProperties: ['name'],
    content: this.get('groups')
  });
}.property('model.selectedGroups'),
```

What happens with this, for some reason, is that when I move the very first group or groups over, they are associated with the user.  However, ANY future change is not.  I look at the data being sent to rails, and it's sending an array of the original values, not the updated ones.

These two are so closely related that their code is very similar.  I've verified that all the code is correct between them.

I know the createWithMixins is not the issue as I've tried removing it and it didn't make any difference, so something else is going on.

One of my question is:  by tying "this.get('groups')" to selectedGroups, is that all it takes for ember to properly associate the data between them?  It appears so as that's what is happening in the group/permission case.  I don't have any other special code doing anything to set things up.

Of course, the bigger question is, am I missing something here?

Any pointers would be appreciated, as I'm really lost on this one.

I know I've only posted a few pieces of my code, but hopefully it's enough to work with.

Comment: How are you setting the data?  Would you mind showing that code?  Also `property('model.selectedGroups')` are more than likely doing nothing, they are telling Ember it's a computed property, but then they are saying watch the property selectedGroups (which lives on the model) and when that changes update this computed property, I doubt this is related at all, just a note that they are watching a non-existent property when trying to figure out if the property is dirty.

Comment: I found my problem.  It was in the serializer in Rails.  It's working properly now.  However, I guess I do need to look into the issue you brought up with the `.property('model.selectedGroups')`.  I copied this from a coworker's code on the same application.